# Did all events in 13 episodes of Mekakucity Actors happen in just 1 day?

Tags: kagerou-project

I heard some rumors saying that all events in *Mekakucity Actors* (all 13 episodes) happened in just one day (in Mekakucity Actors universe).

Is it true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes all the events took place in 1 day. There is no day night switch during the episodes after the moment he spills his drink on his keyboard. It is the 14th august. He then wants to order a new one, but due to the festival going on all shops are only available to deliver at the 17th as earliest date. However one shop is open despite the festival. He thinks he is unable to survive 3 days without his computer so he decides to go outside on the 14th of august. After this choice all the other events happen. Due to the flashbacks it looks like it all happened over a span of time, but in reality it was only 1 day.

Below I have linked the sources I used, along with my memory of the anime. I watched it when it aired so the only part I was confused about was when he spilled the drink and the time between him going to get outside. Hence the second source.

Source 1: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kagerou_Project

Source 2: http://kagerouproject.wikia.com/wiki/Mekakucity_Actors_-_Episode_01